Change enums and OpenAPI spec at runtime
I have a FastAPI application serving data to other systems. This data is categorized (for the sake of the example) by different car manufacturers (e.g., VW, Skoda, ...). In our app, we have a class that walks over our file base and checks which manufacturers currently are available and generates, at startup of the FastAPI, respective enum models. These models are then used as parameter declaration (and thus within the openAPI.json), such that the manufacturers can be selected within the dropdown menu of the SwaggerUI/OpenAPI UI.
I want to be able to periodically "rewalk/reload" the file base, as I continuously add new manufacturers to the data set. However, I always need to restart the FastAPI, as otherwise the models are not generated newly.
Below you find an excerpt of my code.
class carHandler:
    
    ...

    def getCarModel(self, type) -> list:
        tempArr = []
        for manufacturer in self.manufacturers:
            if ((manufacturer.type in type or type == ["all"]):
                tempArr.append((manufacturer.name, manufacturer.name))
        tempArrSorted = sorted(tempArr, key=lambda x: x[0])
        return enum.Enum(f'Available {type}', dict(tempArrSorted))

cH = carHandler()
allowedTruckModel = cH.getCarModel(["trucks"])

...

@self.get("/manufacturer/{name}", tags=["api"])
async def get_truck_manufacturer_information(name: allowedTruckModel) -> models.outputModel:
    return endpoint_logic.get_manufacturer(name)

Here is what I tried so far:

directly use the function call as a parameter, e.g.,
async def get_truck_manufacturer_information(name: cH.getCarModel(["trucks"]))

results in
Call expression not allowed in type expressionPylancereportInvalidTypeForm


update the allowedTruckModel, which does not propagate to the FastAPI.

Looked into restarting/refreshing the FastAPI:
@self.get("/updateCH", include_in_schema=False)
                async def updateCH(request: Request):
                    cH.update()
                    reloadKeys()
                    updateModels()
                    request.app.openapi_schema = None
                    request.app.setup()
                    return f"success"

Did not have an effect on the app.


